# vuejs v-model let it change from one place only

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

hi i have vuejs2 code with laravel blade ..
now my problem is that i have this vuejs2 code

```
new Vue({
    el:'.add_item_to_price_menu',
    data:{
        percentage:null,
    },
    methods:{
        searchData:function(){
            console.log(this.percentage);
        }
    }
});
```

and this is my blade code

```
<input type='text' @keyup='searchData' v-model='percentage' id='percentage' placeholder='{{trans("language.percentage")}}' class='form-control parent' />

<input v-model='percentage' type='text' class='form-control child' />
<input v-model='percentage' type='text' class='form-control child' />
```

now what i want is change the parent class change the values on every child and this is working with me but when i change in child i dont want it change in every anther model percentage is there any way to do that thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be not to use `v-model`, just `:value=percentage`.

`v-model` is syntactic sugar to using a prop and an event.
From [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components):

> the [...] component must:
>
> - Bind the `value` attribute to a `value` prop
> - On input, emit its own custom `input` event with the new value

So if you only use `:value` then it's a one way binding. Just take into account that if the user changes one of those inputs, it won't be reflected in your model.